# Не работает JS код. HTML не видит его что-ли

Tags: javascript

```
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;
var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;
while (isSunk == false) {
  guess = promt("Приготовься стрелять! (Выбери число от 0 до 6):");
  if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
    alert("Пожалуйста введите допустимое число.");
  } else {
    guesses = guesses + 1;
    if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
      alert("Попал!");
      hits = hits + 1;

      if (hits == 3) {
        isSunk = true;
        alert("Молодец, корабль потоплен!");
      } else {
        alert("Не попал.");
      }
    }
  }
}
var work = "Тебе удалось потопить корабль с" + " " + "guesses" + " " + "попыток.";
alert(work);
```

Comment: this ключевое слово, лучше назвать переменную иначе, prompt а не promt,
а там hits, не внимательно посмотрел..

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо вам!